# Como criar um Merged "ResourceDictionaries"

Tags: c#, wpf

Tenho um pequeno exemplo no qual criei um resource ao nível da aplicação:

```
<Application x:Class="teste1.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:teste1"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="texto" Color="Yellow"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="texto1" Color="#FF5E1AC1"/>
    <Color x:Key="fundo1">#FFBF3B3B</Color>
</Application.Resources>
```

O que devo fazer de forma a mudar este "Resource" para um ficheiro à parte de forma a que todas as configurações em termos de estilo fiquem exclusivamente nesse ficheiro?
Tentei algumas pesquisas relacionadas com "Merged ResourceDictionaries" mas sem sucesso.

Só consegui assim. Fará sentido?

```
<Application x:Class="teste1.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:teste1"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <!--<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>-->
        <ResourceDictionary Source="MeuResourceDictionary/MeuResourceDictionary.xaml"/>
    <!--</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>-->
</Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crie um arquivo *xaml* com a declaração do *ResourceDictionary*:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="texto" Color="Yellow"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="texto1" Color="#FF5E1AC1"/>
    <Color x:Key="fundo1">#FFBF3B3B</Color>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Dê-lhe o nome que quiser, ex.: *MeuResourceDictionary.xaml*
Use-o desta forma:

```
<Application x:Class="teste1.App"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:local="clr-namespace:teste1"
     StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">

    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="caminhoAte\MeuResourceDictionary.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
....
....
</Application>
```